# HTML button loaded before the other content of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing an issue like my export button render before the HTML table loaded,which is not looking good on UI.

What I want to achieve is my button load after the table render or once the whole page loaded the content should appear.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableData = [{
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 18
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 55
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 21
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 52
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 38
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
      "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 132
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
      "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
      "AMOUNT": 29
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 165
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 60
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 185
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 100
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 50
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
      "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 1290
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 25
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 5
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 68
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 10
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
      "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 119
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 220
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 12
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
      "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 450
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 115
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 228
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 15
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableData) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first

    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
    // are number
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
    col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];

      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;

        if (j > 1)

          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

      }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");

  }
  addTable(tableData)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Export</button>
<div id="table1">

</div>
```

What I want to achieve is that once the page is fully loaded the export button should come on ui i.e after the table loaded or with table only.

Here in snippet it is loading correctly because here I am statically defining the JSON. In my code I am making an ajax call so when I make that call the button appears on UI before the table loaded.

Comment: Initially make it hide by putting the css and show it when all the content loaded successfully.

Comment: In your snippet here, you could put an artificial delay to better demonstrate your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the button

```
<button id="exportBtn" type="button" style="display: none;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Export</button>
```

Show the button after adding table

```
addTable(tableData)
$("#exportBtn").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using a `Promise` to simulate an AJAX call. This should work for you. I have added an `id` attribute to the button element, is hiding it first and is displaying it after the JSON is fetched.

So what you want to do is hide the button first, wait for the JSON to load through the AJAX request and after it's fetched, display the button using `jQuery`'s `show()` method.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: none" id="exportBtn">Export</button>
    <div id="table1"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var tableData = [
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 18
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 80
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 70
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 55
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 46
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 21
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 40
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 52
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 38
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
          QUANTITY: "4.0000",
          AMOUNT: 132
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
          QUANTITY: "0.1000",
          AMOUNT: 29
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 46
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 70
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 180
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 165
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 60
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 185
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 66
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 100
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 50
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
          QUANTITY: "3.0000",
          AMOUNT: 1290
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 80
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 25
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 5
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 68
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 10
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
          QUANTITY: "5.0000",
          AMOUNT: 119
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 70
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 75
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 75
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 220
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 12
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
          QUANTITY: "2.0000",
          AMOUNT: 180
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 450
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 115
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 66
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 228
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 40
        },
        {
          "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
          "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
          QUANTITY: "1.0000",
          AMOUNT: 15
        }
      ];

      function addTable(tableData) {
        var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first

        var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
        // are number
        var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
        col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
          th.innerHTML = col[i];

          tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
          tr = table.insertRow(-1);

          for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
            if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
              tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString("en-in");
            }
            tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;

            if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
          }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
        table.classList.add("table");
        table.classList.add("table-striped");
        table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      }
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $("#exportBtn").show();
          resolve(tableData);
        }, 2000);
      }).then(data => {
        addTable(data);
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can hide `onpage` load than bind the table grid and show the btn such as below example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnExport").hide();
  var tableData = [{
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 18
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 55
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 21
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 52
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 38
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
      "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 132
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
      "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
      "AMOUNT": 29
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 46
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 165
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 60
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 185
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 100
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 50
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
      "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 1290
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 80
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 25
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 5
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 68
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 10
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
      "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 119
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 70
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 75
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 220
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 12
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
      "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 180
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 450
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 115
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 66
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 228
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 40
    },
    {
      "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
      "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
      "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
      "AMOUNT": 15
    }
  ]

  function addTable(tableData) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first

    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
    // are number
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
    col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];

      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
        if (tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)) {
          tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
        }
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;

        if (j > 1)

          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

      }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");

  }
  addTable(tableData);
  $("#btnExport").show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="btnExport" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Export</button>
<div id="table1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initially hide the button then show that after the call of *addTable()*.

***Please Note:*** All of your code written in JavaScript. It is not good practice to mix JavaScript and jQuery unnecessarily.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
var tableData=[
         {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C001",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Beverages",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 18
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C002",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Shakes",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 80
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C003",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Juices",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 70
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C004",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Soups",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 55
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C005",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Cookies",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 46
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C006",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Buns",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 21
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C007",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Breads",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 40
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C008",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Rusks",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 52
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C009",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Biscuits",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 38
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C010",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Puff",
            "QUANTITY": "4.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 132
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C011",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Savouries",
            "QUANTITY": "0.1000",
            "AMOUNT": 29
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C012",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Cake",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 46
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C014",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "IceCream",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 70
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C019",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Curry",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 180
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C021",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Starter",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 165
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C022",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Roti",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 60
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C023",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Chawal",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 185
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C024",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Dessert",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 66
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C026",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Soup",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 100
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C027",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Salad",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 50
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C028",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Set Menu",
            "QUANTITY": "3.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 1290
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C029",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Pastry",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 80
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C030",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Packed Meals",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 25
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C031",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Packaging",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 5
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C034",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Bhath",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 68
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C036",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Snacks",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 10
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C037",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Breakfast",
            "QUANTITY": "5.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 119
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C038",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Evening Snacks",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 70
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C040",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Sandwich",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 75
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C042",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Burger",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 75
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C043",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Meals",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 220
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C044",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Curd",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 12
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C048",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Combo",
            "QUANTITY": "2.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 180
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C051",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Silver Thali",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 450
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C052",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Sweets",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 115
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C054",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Instant Mixes",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 66
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C055",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "RTE",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 228
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C057",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Spices",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 40
          },
          {
            "CATEGORY CODE": "C061",
            "CATEGORY NAME": "Fast Food",
            "QUANTITY": "1.0000",
            "AMOUNT": 15
          }
        ]

  function addTable(tableData) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]); // get all the keys from first

    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
                              // are number
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
    col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];

        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
             var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
    if(tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)){
      tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
    }
    tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;

              if (j > 1)

              tabCell.classList.add("text-right");

        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("table1");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  }
  addTable(tableData);
  document.querySelector('#btn_export').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#btn_export{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button id="btn_export" type="button" class="export btn btn-primary btn-lg">Export</button>
<div id="table1">

</div>
```

Comment: i don't know how to make ajax call using javascript thats why i am using jquery

Comment: @manishthakur, if you already use jQuery in your code then there is no problem....that's why I have mention the word *unnecessarily*........thanks